# how to set navigate url to hyperlink through c#

Tags: url, user-controls, hyperlink

am developing an application in which i have to show the customer purchase details supplier wise. for that i have develop user control an add it on page. but the problem it that on user control i need to add a ling to promotional offer page for that supplier  which show the current offers of the supplier. for that i have added the hyperlink as fallow to user control

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="PromoLink"  runat="server">Have promo Code ?</asp:HyperLink>
```

and set the navigation URL as fallow

```
PromoLink.NavigateUrl = "Promotion.aspx?Filter=" + dt.Rows[0]["SuppId"].ToString();
```

but when page is load in does not render the navigation url to the link.

i donot why it does not render the url plz help to get out of this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the page loading without a URL set at all? What is the current outcome of clicking the hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the pathing is correct for the NavigateURL property.  Try adding "~/" at the start of the NavigateURL or "../" if it is not in the same folder as the current file.

Make sure that the dt.Rows[0]["SuppId"] is actually getting the value that you expect.

Step through code in the debugger to verify that the Page_Load event that you are using is actually executing and modifying the value as you would expect it to.